# Как такое возможно? Процедура есть в одном представлении, но нет в другом

Tags: sql, oracle

Смотрю в два представления, в одном процедура есть, в другом - нет. При этом успешно дропается.

```
SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EX_LOG_CLEAR
```

Comment: По поводу [удалённого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1251518/217579): секунды не хватило отправить ответ. Какова причина удаления, если не секрет?

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу =) Я понял, что в проекте перечисления использовались совсем не так, как я представил, сказалось моё скудное общение с типами object. Судя по всему, генератор кода, когда в yaml файле встречал сущность с полем типа enum, то просто создавал тип вроде e_myEnum, в который добавлял статические функции. Просто чтобы где-то хранить возможные значения. А само поле делал просто текстовым. Поэтому, фактически в проекте не используется перечисление и по факту на адаптер может прилететь любое текстовое значение. Если что-то понятно из моего потока сознания :)

Comment: Ну всё, что вы описали я понял. А зачем было удалять? Если вы разобрались, то хорошо, но для других потенциальных интересующиеся с гугла вопрос будет тоже интересен. Вопрос высокого качества, и я конечно могу скопировать его и задать от своего имени, но тогда вы потенциально не получите репутацию (хе-хе).

Comment: @0xdb так я и решил, что это я балбес и вопрос слишком низкого качества, хех. Вопросы адекватные я оставляю, пару раз даже отвечал на свой же вопрос :)

Comment: Ну раз решили, хозяин-барин. Вопрос вполне нормальный. Если бы все знали на него ответ, то этот сайт был бы не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В USER_PROCEDURES не попадают процедуры со статусом INVALID.

Проверьте статус процедуры в USER_OBJECTS (Поле STATUS)

Comment: Да, процедура инвалидна. В целом то, в том и проблема. Видимо, XLDeploy настроен так, что при раздеплое грохает все процедуры из USER_PROCEDURES, поэтому оставляет лишний хлам (потом вылезает ошибкой при накате очередной версии). В общем, благодарю. Надо что-то с этим решать, конечно.